# Django:get field values using views.py from html form

Tags: django, forms

Hello everyone I have an HTML form as follows:

```html
<body class="">
    <div class="navbar navbar-static-top navbar-inverse"></div>
    <div style="height:20%; width:30%; margin-top:12%; margin-left:40%;">
        <div class="list-group">
            <form role="form">
            <br/>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch"  ></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="Username" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
                    <input type="text" name="first_name" class="form-control" placeholder="FIRST_NAME" />
                </div>
                <div class="form-group input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-tag"  ></i></span>
                <input type="text" name="last_name" class="form-control" placeholder="LAST_NAME" />
                </div>
                ...
                ...
                <a href="/submit" class="btn btn-success ">POST</a>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

and after clicking on post i am  redirecting it to views.py. can any one tell me how to get the field values of all the fields of the form into views.py. thanks in advance

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Each input should have a name attribute:

```
<input type="text" name="username" class="form-control"
                                      placeholder="Desired Username" />
```

And then in your view you can access that data using `request.POST` or `request.GET` dictionary-like objects (it depends on the `method` attribute of the `<form>` tag):

```
def register(request):
    username = request.POST['username']
    ...
```

But you shouldn't render/handle forms this PHPish way.  Learn the [django forms](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/).

Comment: Request parameters are case-sensitive, so you should access the username as `request.GET['Username']`.  `GET` is the default request method for forms.  To change it to `POST` add the `<form method="POST">` attribute.

Comment: how to check whether i got values in or not

Comment: suppose i want to  display the information what i got in views into other html page, is it possible

Comment: Yes, add the following line to the `register()` function: `return render(request, 'mytemplate.html', {'username': username})` and then in the `mytemplate.html` output the value with `{{ username }}` tag. Look at the tutorial: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render

Comment: CSRF verification failed. Request aborted. error occuring

Comment: This is a completely different question. Please close up this question and ask a new one if you're still having problems.

Comment: i have added {% csrf_tork %} but no use

Comment: Oops, mistype. Add the csrf token after the <form> tag: <form method="POST">{% csrf_token %}. See the example here: docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-to-use-it

Answer (score 7):

To catch the data in python backend

**for POST request:**

```
def register(request):
    username = request.POST.get('username')
```

**for GET request**

```
def register(request):
    username = request.GET.get('username')
```

**.get was missing on earlier  answer**