# How to use Django's HTML form to edit a part of users profile.

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have a user profile model I use django model forms to create and edit the users profiles Now I want to change only 2 fields on the profiles `lat` and `lon` . So on my Index.html I have a small html form . As soon as the user clicks locate me. The latitude and longitude are automatically filed in and the submit button will be clicked using Jquery. How do I use the details from this form to update my users `lat` and `lon`. Its just that I have not used django's HTML form's and I need to update the `lat` `lon` entered on this mini form to the users profile

[image]

```
        <form method="post" action="{{ ??????????? }}">
            <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" >
            <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude">
            <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
```

Do I create another view & url (that way I will have 2 profile edit views and 2 profile edit url's) to add the `lat` and `lon` to my existing profile. Or Is there a way I can use the existing view and url and update the 2 fields

below are my models

```
    class Profile(models.Model):
        user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
        city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        age = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
        profile_image = models.ImageField(default='', blank=True, null=True)
 null=True)
        is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        lat = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
        lon = models.FloatField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Below is my profiles view

```
@login_required
def edit_profile(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        user_form = UserEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(data=request.POST or None, instance=request.user.profile, files=request.FILES)
        if user_form.is_valid() and profile_form.is_valid():
                user_form.save()
                profile_form.save()
            return redirect('accounts:profile', username=request.user.username)
    else:
        user_form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user)
        profile_form = ProfileEditForm(instance=request.user.profile)

    context = {'user_form': user_form,
               'profile_form': profile_form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/profile_edit.html', context)
```

Below are my forms.py

```
class UserEditForm (forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'username')

class ProfileEditForm(forms.ModelForm): #UserProfileForm or ProfileEdit

    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = ('city', 'age', 'profile_image','lat','lon')
```

Below are my urls

```
urlpatterns = [        
    url(r'^profile/(?P<username>[-\w]+)/$', views.ProfileView.as_view(), name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', views.edit_profile, name='edit_profile'),

#Profile created automatically when user is created
]
```

PS: I have trimmed the geodjango code from here as it's not a part of this question

Answer (score 0):

You definitely can edit the details within the post of your view. 
Firstly, in your HTML you should name your inputs.

```
        <form method="post”>
        <input id="jsLat" type="text" placeholder="latittude" name=“Lat” >
        <input id="jsLon" type="text" placeholder="longitude" name=“Long”>
        <button type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

Then in your post view you can retrieve the data by doing: `lat = request.POST[‘Lat’]` or `lon = request.POST[‘Lon’]`

Next step is to update the database entry.

To do this you need to retrieve the user’s object.

```
user = User.objects.get(instance=request.user)
```

Once you have this you can update fields in the following manner:

```
user.latitude = lat
user.longitude = lon 
user.save()
```

Further reference:

[1. Retrieving data from HTML form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228627/djangoget-field-values-using-views-py-from-html-form)

[2. Updating database entry](https://www.packtpub.com/mapt/book/web_development/9781787121386/6/ch06lvl1sec54/updating-records-in-the-database)

Hope this helps!

**Edit:**

It is rather recommended that you have the form as a Django form and then simply [add the desired HTML attribute there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902008/django-how-do-i-add-arbitrary-html-attributes-to-input-fields-on-a-form). This allows you to call the form as you usually would for a Django form.

Comment: what is the form action

Comment: Also where will I add `request.user.profile.lat = Lat` I cannot add it in the existing view as the `if request.method == 'POST':` is actually calling the profile edit form which is different from the simple HTML form in the index.html

Comment: Pardon me but you should be using a Django form instead of using request.POST

Comment: @e4c5, Yes, Django form is much more of a preference, yet if it is not an option this is still a possibility.

Comment: Felix there's almost never a case when getting raw data from request.get or request.post is the right approach