# How can I perform sorting on browsed items in Django

Tags: html, django

As in title. I have a problem becasue I am not able to sort items which I browsed. Or should I use Javascript than pure Django to perform things like these?

views.py

```
def searchView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = request.GET.get('search')
        if not context:
            context = ""
        items = Item.objects.all().filter(title__icontains=context)
        
        try:
            sorting_method = request.GET.get('select')
            if sorting_method == 'v1':
                items = items.order_by('price')
            elif sorting_method == 'v2':
                items = items.order_by('-price')
            else: 
                return render(request, 'shop/search.html', {'items': items})
            return render(request, 'shop/sort.html', {'items': items})
        except UnboundLocalError:
            return redirect('home-page')
```

HTML :

```
<form action="{% url 'search-page'%}" class="navbar__search-form" method="GET">
 <input name="search" class="navbar__search-text" type="text" placeholder="Search for an item.">
</form>

<form action="{% url 'search-page'%}" class = "sort__form" method="GET">
        <h1 class="sort__header"> SORT ITEMS </h1>
            <select class= "sort__select" name="select">
                <option disabled selected> Sorting method</option>
                <option value="v1">Price: low to high</option>
                <option value="v2">Price: high to low</option>
            </select>
         <button class="sort__submit">SORT</button>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

In your HTML code try to use 'name' instead 'value' it could help. For example:

```
<option name="v1">Price: low to high</option>
```

source: [Django:get field values using views.py from html form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29228627/djangoget-field-values-using-views-py-from-html-form/49942684)

Regarding to your function name searchView(request).
In Python we are using snake_case for function naming (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case).
CamelCase is reserved for class naming.

regards

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have done it, the problem was 2 diffrent forms.

```
views.py 

search_history = []
def searchView(request):
    if request.method == "GET":
        context = request.GET.get('search')
        if not context:
            context = search_history[-1]
       search_history.append(context)
        items = Item.objects.all().filter(title__icontains=search_history[-1])
        try:
            sorting_method = request.GET.get('select')
            if sorting_method == 'v1':
                items = items.order_by('price')
                return render(request, 'shop/search.html', {'items': items})
            if sorting_method == 'v2':
                items = items.order_by('-price')
                return render(request, 'shop/search.html', {'items': items})
            else:
                return render(request, 'shop/search.html', {'items': items})
        except UnboundLocalError:
            return redirect('home-page')
```

I would be pleased if someone can tell me is using `search_history = []` good idea.